# How to specify autocorrelation in GAMM?

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation, generalized-additive-model

I am trying to fit a generalised additive model to my data (s. below for R dput), which consists of one value per year for each id.

[image]

```
> head(test)
  year  val    id
1 1930 1.40 te_01
2 1931 2.04 te_01
3 1932 1.40 te_01
4 1933 1.48 te_01
5 1934 1.25 te_01
6 1935 1.12 te_01

library(mgcv)
m1 <- gamm(val ~ s(year), data = test)

acf(resid(m1$lme, type = "normalized"))
pacf(resid(m1$lme, type = "normalized"))
```

[image]

Looking at the (p)acf plots I am clueless as to how to incorporate the autocorrelation into the model. Can you give me some hints?

```
test <- structure(list(year = c(1930, 1931, 1932, 1933, 1934, 1935, 1936, 
1937, 1938, 1939, 1940, 1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1945, 1946, 1947, 
1948, 1949, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 
1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 
1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 
1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 
1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 
2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 1930, 1931, 1932, 
1933, 1934, 1935, 1936, 1937, 1938, 1939, 1940, 1941, 1942, 1943, 
1944, 1945, 1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 
1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 
1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 
1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 
1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 
1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 1930, 1931, 1932, 1933, 1934, 1935, 1936, 1937, 1938, 1939, 
1940, 1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1945, 1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 1950, 
1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 
1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 
1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 
1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 
1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 
2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 1930, 1931, 1932, 1933, 1934, 1935, 
1936, 1937, 1938, 1939, 1940, 1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1945, 1946, 
1947, 1948, 1949, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 
1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 
1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 
1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 
1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 
2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 1930, 1931, 
1932, 1933, 1934, 1935, 1936, 1937, 1938, 1939, 1940, 1941, 1942, 
1943, 1944, 1945, 1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 
1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 
1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 
1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 
1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 
1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 
2009, 2010, 1930, 1931, 1932, 1933, 1934, 1935, 1936, 1937, 1938, 
1939, 1940, 1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1945, 1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 
1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 
1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 
1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 
1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 
1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 1930, 1931, 1932, 1933, 1934, 
1935, 1936, 1937, 1938, 1939, 1940, 1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1945, 
1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 
1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 
1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 
1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 
1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 
2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 1930, 
1931, 1932, 1933, 1934, 1935, 1936, 1937, 1938, 1939, 1940, 1941, 
1942, 1943, 1944, 1945, 1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 1950, 1951, 1952, 
1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 
1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 
1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 
1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 
1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 1930, 1931, 1932, 1933, 1934, 1935, 1936, 1937, 
1938, 1939, 1940, 1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1945, 1946, 1947, 1948, 
1949, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 
1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 
1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 
1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 
1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 
2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 1930, 1931, 1932, 1933, 
1934, 1935, 1936, 1937, 1938, 1939, 1940, 1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 
1945, 1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 
1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 
1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 
1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 
1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 
2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 
1930, 1931, 1932, 1933, 1934, 1935, 1936, 1937, 1938, 1939, 1940, 
1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1945, 1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 1950, 1951, 
1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 
1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 
1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 
1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 
1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 1930, 1931, 1932, 1933, 1934, 1935, 1936, 
1937, 1938, 1939, 1940, 1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1945, 1946, 1947, 
1948, 1949, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 
1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 
1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 
1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 
1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 
2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 1930, 1931, 1932, 
1933, 1934, 1935, 1936, 1937, 1938, 1939, 1940, 1941, 1942, 1943, 
1944, 1945, 1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 
1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 
1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 
1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 
1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 
1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 1930, 1931, 1932, 1933, 1934, 1935, 1936, 1937, 1938, 1939, 
1940, 1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1945, 1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 1950, 
1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 
1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 
1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 
1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 
1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 
2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 1930, 1931, 1932, 1933, 1934, 1935, 
1936, 1937, 1938, 1939, 1940, 1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1945, 1946, 
1947, 1948, 1949, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 
1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 
1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 
1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 
1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 
2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010), val = c(1.4, 
2.04, 1.4, 1.48, 1.25, 1.12, 1.88, 2.02, 2.3, 1.78, 2.22, 1.92, 
2.47, 2.12, 2.75, 1.61, 1.93, 1.48, 2.8, 1.62, 3.41, 2.6, 1.78, 
2.72, 3.11, 2.66, 2.57, 2.69, 2.99, 1.7, 3.19, 2.63, 2.08, 3.1, 
2, 2.57, 3.1, 3.11, 3.38, 2.34, 2.72, 1.99, 3.07, 3.04, 4.36, 
4.09, 1.31, 3.17, 2.88, 2.06, 2.65, 1.48, 3.81, 2.59, 2.83, 3.33, 
3.95, 4.4, 4.15, 2.37, 2.6, 2.59, 2.24, 2.85, 3.51, 2.41, 2.2, 
3.22, 2.16, 2.66, 1.74, 1.75, 2.62, 2.71, 2.7, 3.68, 2.38, 5.33, 
3.34, 3.01, 2.8, 1.31, 2.31, 1.9, 1.63, 1.22, 1.04, 2.02, 1.58, 
2.13, 1.88, 1.82, 1.76, 1.61, 1.63, 1.76, 1.2, 1.67, 0.81, 2.35, 
1.58, 3.17, 4.54, 2.78, 5.4, 5.37, 4.84, 3.48, 2.85, 2.73, 2.32, 
3.13, 2.58, 2.35, 3.55, 1.88, 2.7, 3.35, 3.45, 3.47, 3.11, 3.88, 
3.17, 3.46, 4.09, 4.59, 3.85, 1.21, 2.64, 3.51, 2.38, 2.74, 2.02, 
3.48, 2.06, 2.14, 2.5, 3.14, 3.31, 3.17, 2.05, 1.83, 1.53, 1.69, 
2.6, 3.21, 2.97, 3.26, 3.59, 2.62, 2.02, 1.71, 1.78, 1.96, 1.74, 
1.97, 2.17, 1.66, 2.34, 1.97, 1.39, 1.28, 3.02, 3.6, 4.1, 3.35, 
2.68, 2.48, 3.17, 2.3, 2.81, 2.19, 2.71, 2.34, 2.91, 3.29, 3.53, 
2.62, 3.08, 1.83, 2.5, 1.78, 2.74, 3.38, 2.07, 2.28, 2.6, 2.91, 
2.3, 1.95, 2.92, 1.55, 1.54, 2.6, 1.84, 2.65, 1.97, 1.7, 2.1, 
2.1, 2.37, 1.86, 1.75, 2.23, 2.27, 2.8, 2.37, 2.31, 1.23, 1.34, 
2.25, 2.01, 2.02, 1.22, 1.84, 1.76, 1.5, 1.45, 1.65, 1.98, 2.22, 
1.82, 1.88, 1.91, 1.35, 1.27, 1.8, 2.39, 1.7, 2.43, 1.86, 1.79, 
1.66, 1.43, 1.25, 1.39, 0.76, 1.31, 1.2, 0.55, 0.94, 0.68, 0.57, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.16, 2.56, 2.42, 2.98, 3.34, 4.19, 
2.77, 3.78, 1.43, 3.6, 1.91, 3.77, 4.97, 2.61, 3.5, 3.85, 4.4, 
3.48, 3.19, 4.39, 2.69, 3.05, 3.84, 2.44, 4.35, 2.16, 2.22, 3.33, 
3.4, 3.58, 3.44, 3.53, 2.97, 3.41, 2.9, 3.4, 3.43, 4.22, 3.78, 
1.45, 1.51, 2.69, 2.45, 3.2, 1.1, 1.53, 0.95, 0.94, 1.7, 1.9, 
3.49, 3.64, 1.98, 1.6, 1.81, 0.63, 0.58, 2.11, 1.47, 1.43, 2.77, 
1.59, 1.77, 1.44, 1.24, 1.16, 1.14, 0.89, 1.57, 1.1, 1.47, 1.84, 
0.47, 0.68, 1.31, 2.04, 2.25, 1.49, 0.77, 1.26, 2.21, 1.55, 2.28, 
1.36, 1.05, 1.05, 0.82, 1.58, 1.84, 0.97, 0.86, 0.59, 0.51, 1.71, 
4.43, 4.41, 2.96, 4.6, 4.99, 4.45, 3.95, 2.6, 4.44, 2.4, 3.69, 
4.01, 2.74, 3.25, 1.85, 2.84, 4.05, 3.48, 2.65, 3.37, 3.86, 3.91, 
4.08, 4.37, 3.99, 4.6, 1.51, 3.6, 4.64, 3.37, 4.61, 2.53, 3.6, 
2.5, 2.1, 1.9, 2.57, 2.75, 3.54, 2.04, 2.4, 2.54, 1.23, 0.81, 
2.42, 1.8, 2.48, 3.68, 2.42, 2.54, 2.15, 2, 2.23, 2.05, 1.93, 
1.64, 1.52, 2.1, 2.41, 1.31, 0.55, 3.19, 3.05, 2.48, 1.26, 0.61, 
1.27, 2.52, 1.58, 2.34, 1.91, 1.53, 2.01, 2.04, 2.15, 2.58, 1.42, 
1.46, 1.15, 1.63, 0.85, 1.52, 2.34, 1.32, 2.34, 2.14, 2.09, 1.99, 
1.7, 2.72, 1.62, 3.29, 2.94, 2.54, 2.94, 1.52, 1.99, 3.31, 3.07, 
4.16, 3.52, 3.18, 2.53, 3.04, 3.34, 2.4, 2.88, 1.11, 3.35, 3.53, 
2.57, 3.22, 2.73, 3.35, 1.88, 1.85, 1.72, 2.32, 3.23, 3.14, 1.37, 
1.64, 1.71, 0.84, 0.93, 1.98, 1.92, 2.2, 3.33, 2.23, 2.39, 1.83, 
1.87, 1.74, 1.43, 1.06, 1.66, 1.83, 2.22, 1.78, 1.06, 0.42, NA, 
NA, 2.21, 1.85, 1.2, 1.06, 1.81, 1.46, 2.12, 1.56, 1.79, 1.97, 
2.9, 2.65, 3.09, 1.97, 2.69, 1.16, 2.06, 1, 1.69, 2.24, 1.38, 
2.56, 2.58, 2.46, 2.43, 1.88, 2.4, 1.29, 2.18, 2.5, 2.4, 2.76, 
1.83, 2.36, 3.24, 3.37, 3.37, 3.21, 3.38, 3, 3.78, 4.42, 5.58, 
4.55, 1.82, 3.83, 4.3, 2.91, 3.48, 2.1, 3, 1.75, 1.25, 1.51, 
1, 1.56, 2.39, 1.65, 2.05, 2.27, 1.29, 3.01, 3.7, 2.8, 3.12, 
3.6, 2.61, 2.51, 1.85, 2.08, 2.61, 1.46, 1.76, 2.79, 1.59, 2.65, 
2.14, 1.7, 1.69, 1.59, 2.34, 2.26, 1.88, 1.69, 1.51, 2.77, 2.31, 
2.87, 2.4, 2.62, 2.18, 2.83, 2.67, 2.36, 1.18, 2.04, 1.71, 2.19, 
1.64, 2.5, 4.13, 2.87, 3.89, 4.25, 4.32, 3.33, 3.15, 4.52, 2.97, 
3.75, 3.84, 2.88, 3.48, 2.21, 3.62, 3.43, 3.56, 2.77, 2.47, 2.66, 
2.58, 2.38, 2.27, 2.72, 2.32, 1.4, 2.04, 2.42, 1.95, 2.22, 1.56, 
2.78, 2.19, 2.48, 2.8, 3.53, 3.19, 3.15, 2.51, 2.97, 2.78, 1.9, 
2.5, 3.56, 3.84, 3.86, 4.29, 3.83, 4.98, 3.05, 3.17, 3.23, 2.97, 
1.94, 2.67, 1.26, 2.42, 2.86, 2.94, 2.06, 1.86, 2.89, 2.79, 2.27, 
1.68, 1.56, 2.79, 2.07, 2.18, 1.85, 1.76, 1.65, 2.39, 2.22, 2.09, 
1.43, 2.51, 1.78, 2.44, 1.35, 2.39, 3.18, 1.89, 2.76, 2.53, 2.11, 
2.09, 1.98, 2.33, 1.27, 1.76, 2.4, 2.18, 2.26, 1.39, 1.76, 2.05, 
2.45, 2.22, 1.72, 1.5, 1.14, 2.04, 1.63, 2.27, 2.22, 0.95, 1.45, 
1.6, 1.49, 1.51, 1.1, 2.52, 1.44, 1.67, 1.68, 2.14, 3.47, 3.58, 
2.19, 2.09, 1.6, 0.65, 1.01, 2.06, 2.09, 2.71, 3.58, 2.65, 2.52, 
1.27, 1.06, 1.75, 1.9, 1.77, 1.83, 1.35, 2.07, 1.58, 0.82, 0.7, 
0.51, 1.54, 1.44, 1.18, 0.7, 0.46, 0.67, 0.61, 0.95, 0.69, 1.03, 
1.11, 1.48, 1.45, 1.49, 1.1, 1.12, 0.64, 1.44, 0.61, 1.69, 2.81, 
1.82, 2.67, 2.67, 2.37, 2.48, 1.68, 2.3, 1.48, 2.12, 1.79, 1.84, 
2.09, 1.31, 1.4, 1.88, 2.25, 2.08, 2.16, 2.08, 1.79, 2, 2.1, 
2.27, 1.87, 1.02, 1.6, 2.07, 1.52, 2.16, 1.34, 2.76, 2.02, 2.42, 
2.53, 3.25, 3.67, 3.91, 2.52, 2.98, 2.39, 2.19, 2.41, 4.16, 3.95, 
3.9, 5.08, 4.54, 5.51, 4.49, 3.88, 4.6, 3.19, 2.25, 3.21, 2.66, 
3.74, 2.28, 2.34, 1.76, 1.83, 2.82, 2.23, 2.08, 1.91, 1.42, 3.12, 
2.32, 3.34, 2.83, 2.39, 2.53, 4.09, 3.38, 4.51, 2.43, 2.66, 1.34, 
2.87, 1.24, 2.55, 3.57, 2.09, 1.56, 2.15, 2.12, 2.04, 1.25, 2.03, 
1.2, 1.5, 1.57, 1.22, 1.36, 1.51, 1.37, 1.82, 2.11, 1.77, 1.33, 
1.71, 1.5, 1.38, 1.08, 1.42, 1.46, 0.82, 1.41, 1.81, 1.44, 1.76, 
1.43, 1.63, 1.44, 1.54, 1.19, 2.12, 2.2, 2.24, 1.61, 1.72, 1.88, 
1.77, 2.79, 2.93, 2.14, 2.25, 2.78, 2.43, 2.1, 1.35, 1.71, 1.35, 
1.61, 0.81, 1.25, 1.08, 1.03, 1.32, 0.93, 0.58, 2.14, 2.9, 2.74, 
2.3, 1.85, 1.64, 2.99, 2.16, 3.66, 2.44, 2.13, 1.99, 2.44, 2.73, 
3.12, 2.08, 2.57, 1.76, 2.67, 1.94, 2, 3.14, 1.88, 2.49, 2.65, 
2.48, 2.57, 2.24, 2.77, 1.96, 3.01, 2.77, 2.36, 2.81, 1.78, 1.79, 
1.53, 2.02, 2.11, 1.84, 1.67, 1.71, 1.83, 1.92, 2.46, 2.04, 1.2, 
1.59, 2.22, 2.05, 2.07, 1.33, 2.01, 1.26, 1.68, 1.67, 2.1, 2.74, 
3.32, 2.72, 2.41, 2.46, 1.39, 0.88, 1.98, 1.96, 1.9, 2.64, 2.22, 
1.85, 1.22, 1.15, 1.34, 0.78, 0.72, 0.86, 0.59, 0.64, 1.02, 0.41, 
0.3, 1.44, 2.75, 2.99, 2.76, 1.74, 1.71, 3.59, 3.42, 4.17, 3.23, 
3.2, 2.94, 3.62, 3.65, 2.93, 1.45, 1.89, 1.15, 1.66, 1.61, 2.74, 
3.81, 2.33, 2.3, 2.36, 2.36, 2.36, 1.51, 2.06, 1.35, 1.67, 1.7, 
1.35, 1.26, 0.88, 1.55, 1.6, 1.77, 2.27, 1.72, 1.93, 1.94, 2.45, 
2.23, 3, 2.7, 1.13, 2.11, 2.41, 1.7, 1.84, 1.15, 2.29, 1.59, 
0.79, 2.23, 2.52, 3.17, 2.6, 1.37, 2, 1.78, 1.31, 1.28, 2.73, 
1.86, 1.92, 3.19, 2.83, 3.1, 1.95, 2.19, 2.02, 1.69, 1.37, 1.27, 
1.01, 1.39, 1.53, 0.53, 0.47, 1.43, 1.95, 2.19, 2.11, 1.46, 1.34, 
2.32, 1.45, 2.17, 1.35, 1.81, 2.41, 3.01, 2.76, 3.11, 1.54, 2.25, 
1.14, 2.01, 1.35, 2.91, 2.76, 1.74, 2.35, 2.27, 2.31, 2.03, 1.82, 
2.5, 1.95, 3.55, 3.55, 2.83, 3.3, 2.02, 2.52, 3.44, 3.68, 3.29, 
2.6, 3, 2.34, 2.81, 3.69, 3.52, 2.81, 1.07, 1.83, 2.65, 2.17, 
2.45, 1.65, 2.75, 1.53, 1.91, 2.12, 2.54, 3.06, 3.04, 1.35, 1.69, 
1.49, 2.14, 2.4, 2.86, 2.23, 2.06, 2.95, 2.08, 2.21, 1.47, 1.39, 
1.7, 1.31, 1.16, 1.85, 1.41, 1.74, 1.26, 1.73, 1.52, 1.01, 1.31, 
1.49, 1.65, 1.22, 1.28, 1.74, 1.69, 1.86, 1.44, 1.83, 1.65, 1.95, 
2.02, 2.18, 1.78, 1.72, 1.56, 2.05, 1.4, 1.84, 2.37, 1.2, 1.52, 
2.57, 2.66, 2.23, 1.71, 2.27, 1.55, 1.86, 2.09, 1.46, 2.25, 1.73, 
2.14, 2.68, 2.16, 2.64, 2.49, 3.02, 2.41, 2.14, 2.02, 2.31, 2.72, 
1.46, 1.4, 2.29, 1.26, 1.94, 2.14, 3.71, 2.36, 1.65, 2.14, 2.6, 
3.65, 3.11, 1.29, 1.66, 1.89, 1.76, 2.03, 2.75, 1.39, 1.83, 1.78, 
2.06, 1.81, 2.01, 1.79, 1.89, 2.31, 1.32, 1.56, 1.63, 1.94, 2.19, 
2.07, 1.54), id = c("te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", 
"te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", 
"te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", 
"te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", 
"te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", 
"te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", 
"te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", 
"te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", 
"te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", 
"te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", 
"te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", 
"te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_01", "te_02", 
"te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", 
"te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", 
"te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", 
"te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", 
"te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", 
"te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", 
"te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", 
"te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", 
"te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", 
"te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", 
"te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_02", 
"te_02", "te_02", "te_02", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", 
"te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", 
"te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", 
"te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", 
"te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", 
"te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", 
"te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", 
"te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", 
"te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", 
"te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", 
"te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", 
"te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", "te_03", 
"te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", 
"te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", 
"te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", 
"te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", 
"te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", 
"te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", 
"te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", 
"te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", 
"te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", 
"te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", 
"te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", 
"te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_04", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", 
"te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", 
"te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", 
"te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", 
"te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", 
"te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", 
"te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", 
"te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", 
"te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", 
"te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", 
"te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", 
"te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", "te_05", 
"te_05", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", 
"te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", 
"te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", 
"te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", 
"te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", 
"te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", 
"te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", 
"te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", 
"te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", 
"te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", 
"te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", 
"te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_06", "te_07", "te_07", 
"te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", 
"te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", 
"te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", 
"te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", 
"te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", 
"te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", 
"te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", 
"te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", 
"te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", 
"te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", 
"te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", "te_07", 
"te_07", "te_07", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", 
"te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", 
"te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", 
"te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", 
"te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", 
"te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", 
"te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", 
"te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", 
"te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", 
"te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", 
"te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", 
"te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_08", "te_09", 
"te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", 
"te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", 
"te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", 
"te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", 
"te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", 
"te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", 
"te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", 
"te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", 
"te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", 
"te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", 
"te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_09", 
"te_09", "te_09", "te_09", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", 
"te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", 
"te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", 
"te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", 
"te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", 
"te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", 
"te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", 
"te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", 
"te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", 
"te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", 
"te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", 
"te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", "te_10", 
"te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", 
"te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", 
"te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", 
"te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", 
"te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", 
"te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", 
"te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", 
"te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", 
"te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", 
"te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", 
"te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", 
"te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_11", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", 
"te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", 
"te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", 
"te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", 
"te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", 
"te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", 
"te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", 
"te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", 
"te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", 
"te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", 
"te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", 
"te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", "te_12", 
"te_12", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", 
"te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", 
"te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", 
"te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", 
"te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", 
"te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", 
"te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", 
"te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", 
"te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", 
"te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", 
"te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", 
"te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_13", "te_14", "te_14", 
"te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", 
"te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", 
"te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", 
"te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", 
"te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", 
"te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", 
"te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", 
"te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", 
"te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", 
"te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", 
"te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", "te_14", 
"te_14", "te_14", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", 
"te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", 
"te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", 
"te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", 
"te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", 
"te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", 
"te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", 
"te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", 
"te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", 
"te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", 
"te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", 
"te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15", "te_15")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1215L), .Names = c("year", "val", "id"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gamm` uses `nlme:::lme` under the hood. You can specify an auto-correlation structure in exactly the same way as with `lme`. [Zuur et al.](http://www.highstat.com/book2.htm) advice against making the correlation structure too complicated. `corCAR1` (AR1 with a time covariate) is probably sufficient. Don't forget the grouping by ID (as you did in the plots)

```
library(mgcv)
m1 <- gamm(val ~ s(year), data = test)
pacf(resid(m1$lme, type = "normalized")[test$id == "te_01"])
pacf(resid(m1$lme, type = "normalized")[test$id == "te_02"])
pacf(resid(m1$lme, type = "normalized")[test$id == "te_03"])
#...
```

Generally, lag 1 seems to give a correlation value around 0.5. Thus, we specify a corresponding auto-regressive model and use this value as a starting value for the numerics.

```
m2 <- gamm(val ~ s(year), data = test, 
       correlation = corCAR1(value = 0.5, form = ~ year | id))
summary(m2$lme)
#Phi: 0.6
pacf(resid(m2$lme, type = "normalized")[test$id == "te_01"])
pacf(resid(m2$lme, type = "normalized")[test$id == "te_02"])
pacf(resid(m2$lme, type = "normalized")[test$id == "te_03"])
#...
```

These look mostly pretty decent and I would leave it at that.

However, I'm a bit skeptical regarding using time for the smoother *and* the AR structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. My question was more aimed at how to read the acf plot in respect to translating its information into a fitting correlation structure (e.g. why did you choose value = 0.5?). Maybe you can elaborate a bit on that if possible? Thanks for the hint with the grouping id, too.

Comment: Well, you look at the partial ACF plots for each group. If lag 1 gives a strong correlation, you try a structure of first order. If later lags give strong correlation you might need higher order correlation structures, but you should try order 1 first. I've use the values in the plots usually as starting values for the correlation structure.  The decision between auto-regressive and moving-average structures is a bit more difficult, but I've personally never had data where an MA model fit better than  an AR model.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Why could it be a problem to use time for smoother and AR structure?

Comment: That's just a hunch, but I'm not sure how both models interact in such a case and if the result is something sensible. You have a lot of freedom in a smoother and it might model part of the auto-correlation, too.